# Mac hook function

Tags: macos, cocoa, hook, mach

I used to be able to use mach_override to hook any exported function on Mac OS including Catalina. However, now the target app crashed every time and I check the Console and find the following error:

**CODE SIGNING: 30911[app] vm_map_protect can't have both write and exec at the same time**

What's going on and is that possible I can bypass it without touching the target app's signature?

Answer (score 0):

The hardened runtime is designed specifically to prevent that sort of hooking. The target app's entitlements would have to opt-in to allowing it. If you find a way around it, Apple would consider that a security hole bug and patch it in a future OS release.

It should work if you disable System Integrity Protection, but I don't know if that suits your purpose.